# Error when upgrading libcurl with yum on RHEL 6.6

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel6

I am trying to update libcurl on a RHEL 6 server by means of `yum update libcurl`. When I do this I get the following error:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-40.el6_6.4 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl = 7.19.7-40.el6_6.4 for package: libcurl-devel-7.19.7-40.el6_6.4.x86_64
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.19.7-46.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libcurl-devel.x86_64 0:7.19.7-40.el6_6.4 will be updated
---> Package libcurl-devel.x86_64 0:7.19.7-46.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                  Arch                              Version                                   Repository                                          Size
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 libcurl                                  x86_64                            7.19.7-46.el6                             xxx-patch-nonprod-rhel-6                            168 k
Updating for dependencies:
 libcurl-devel                            x86_64                            7.19.7-46.el6                             xxx-patch-nonprod-rhel-6                            246 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade       2 Package(s)

Total size: 415 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libcurl(x86-64) = 7.39.0-1.0.cf.rhel6 is needed by (installed) curl-7.39.0-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
curl-7.39.0-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64 has missing requires of libcurl(x86-64) = ('0', '7.39.0', '1.0.cf.rhel6')
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with: yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2015-08-11-12-01SQI5ei.yumtx
```

Any suggestions how I could resolve this?

Comment: You're trying to get `curl` from `xxx-patch-nonprod-rhel-6`. Is that intended? What kind of repositories do you have enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has a copy of `curl` from the [third party `city-fan` repository](http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/) installed. Unfortunately someone didn't install it *correctly* and its `libcurl` dependency does not match the version of `curl`, because `libcurl` is still the one shipped by Red Hat.

How you resolve this depends on whether you really intended to use the `city-fan` copy of `curl`, or whether it should be removed and replaced with the Red Hat distributed version.

If you intend to use `city-fan` then enable its repository (which is either disabled or not present) and try your original command again. I do not recommend using this repository unless you know exactly what you are doing and can resolve the dependency issues which are certain to follow. (If you could, you wouldn't be here right now, so I *strongly* recommend against using this repo.)

If you intend to use the Red Hat distributed software, remove the `city-fan` repository if it is present, and run `yum distro-sync`. Note that in addition to replacing the third party package, this will also bring the system up to date.